# Quarto file not producing data table

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I am very new to Quarto and I am trying to create an markdown document using it. Everything works well except I am not able to render tables on the output HMTL file.
The following is my code. The HTML document shows ':: {.cell-output-display}' where the table is supposed to be rendered. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out with this.

```
process_results <- function(value){
    results <- topTable(fit2, coef=value,n=Inf,sort.by = 'p') 
    top_results <- head(results, n = 10) %>%
    kable(caption = value) %>%     ### This works on traditional mardown. 
    kable_styling()
    ...........
    ..............
}    
 


 process_results('GroupB_vs_GroupA')
```

Comment: If you run the code in the console, does it produce a table? (kable and kable_styling work fine for me)

Answer (score 1):

The function doesn't return a value is the problem.

```
library(kableExtra)
process_results <- function(value){
    #results <- topTable(fit2, coef=value,n=Inf,sort.by = 'p') 
    top_results <- head(mtcars, n = 10) %>%
    kable(caption = value) %>%     ### This works on traditional mardown. 
    kable_styling()
    return(top_results)
}
process_results('GroupB_vs_GroupA')
```